# Using SqlCommandProvider with custom timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, f#

I am a big fan of `SqlCommandProvider` type provider but I am constantly hitting timeout problems with a bit more resource demanding queries. I set connection timeout in connection string to some bigger value but this still doesn't help me with my queries timing out since that is only for the connection part not for command timeout.

One solution would be to use `AsSqlCommand` set `CommandTimeout` and execute reader but that somewhat kills the point of using the `SqlCommandProvider`.

Any idea how can I set the timeout in constructor / execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timeout support was implemented recently, see 
https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/blob/master/src/SqlClient.Tests/TypeProviderTest.fs#L119

Comment: new link: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/blob/4450560810f0970894d6a46226dae1ca55d7640d/tests/SqlClient.Tests/TypeProviderTest.fs#L129